# Nativescript angular using dialog confirm

Tags: dialog, angular2-nativescript

I have a utils class which contains the showMsg function to use the ui/dialogs

```
showMsg(titleTxt: string, msg: string, btnTxt: string, type: string){
 switch(type){
   case 'confirm':
    dialogs.confirm({
          title: titleTxt,
          message: msg,
          okButtonText: btnTxt,
          cancelButtonText: 'No'
      }).then((result) => {
          console.log(titleTxt + " Dialog closed!" + result);
          return result;
    });
      break;
  default:
    dialogs.alert({
          title: titleTxt,
          message: msg,
          okButtonText: btnTxt
      }).then(() => {
          console.log(titleTxt + " Dialog closed!");
          return true;
    });
}
```

}

The problem is when I call this function from another component for a confirm dialog, the component doesn't wait for the result from the dialog box before continuing. I want it to conditionally continue based on the user response.

edit:

The new showMsg function

```
showMsg(titleTxt: string, msg: string, btnTxt: string, type: string){
   switch(type.toLowerCase()){
  case 'confirm':
    return dialogs.confirm({
          title: titleTxt,
          message: msg,
          okButtonText: btnTxt,
          cancelButtonText: 'No'
      }).then((result) => {
          console.log(titleTxt + " Dialog closed!" + result);
          return result;
    });
  default:
   return dialogs.alert({
          title: titleTxt,
          message: msg,
          okButtonText: btnTxt
      }).then(() => {
          console.log(titleTxt + " Dialog closed!");
          return true;
    });
  }
}
```

The call to the showMsg function is now this

```
        this.myutil.showMsg('Update Cleaning Status', 'Are you Sure?', 'Yes', 'Confirm').then((result)=> { 
            console.log('In then: ' + result);
            alert(result);
         });
```

Unfortunately we can't have any code after the call to the function as it get executed before what happens in the .then()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will definitely not wait as it is a promise. You have to use either the `async/await` [helpers](https://www.nativescript.org/blog/use-async-await-with-typescript-in-nativescript-today) Or wait for `showMsg` to finish, for example `showMsg().then((result)=> { //anything you want to do after dialog is closed })` in your component.

Comment: Thank you for your response, what i was missing was a return before the dialogs call, as putting the .then on the showMsg call was giving a 'then' does not exist on type 'void'

I've updated the question with my solution.